# How did Indy get to the temple with the golden monkey?

Tags: indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

So, I was re-watching *Raiders of the Lost Ark* last night, and something about the beginning bothered me. When Indy gets in the plane, he's beset upon by a giant snake. He flips out about this, yelling to Jock that he hates snakes. But, if Jock flew him there, wouldn't he have known about the snake? So, how did Indy get there to begin with? And if he didn't fly with Jock, why not leave the same way?

Comment: Maybe the snake was in a bag during the inbound flight? That scene was probably just a mechanic, to show us Indie's fear of snakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear from the [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/RaidersoftheLostArk.pdf) (or the [official novelisation](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark_(novel)) or the [comic-book conversion](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Raiders_of_the_Lost_Ark_(comic))) how Indy actually got to the temple. It's pretty clear that he's traveling with two companions and that he (or they) somehow made contact with the locals before traveling to the jungle temple. The plane is certainly *waiting* for him, but there's no special indication that he used it for the outward journey, especially given that they've got mules and supplies.

---

Given that the plane is a two-seater it's very possible that Jock and his plane were chartered **only for the return journey** which would explain why Indy hadn't encountered Reggie before.

Failing that, it's reasonable to assume that Jock (who evidently wasn't expecting Indy to return so soon) had released Reggie from a bag or from under his own seat into the plane's second seat. He may have planned to return him to his bag except that they had to take off in a hurry.

Comment: My impression is that he was following the initial trail of another archaeologist - the one that was found impaled.  He was consulting a journal or a map on the way in, wasn't he?  Probably started from last known location of the dead guy.

Comment: @Radhil - Here's a question I can't answer, how were they all going to leave the jungle in a two-man plane? Was it going to ferry them out one at a time and return for the others?

Comment: Without an entire tribe of hostiles throwing javelins, I could see more of the party being able to get on the plane.  Or it was always intended that the locals walk out and Indy gets the luxury ride.  Either that or they ride on the wings.  Worked in The Mummy.